# CSS Selectors with double dash

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, bem

I am trying to understand CSS selectors that include a double dash (e.g. `.header-module--socialHeaderButton--1BLVB`) that are generated through react.js and behave differently from standard CSS selectors. I am hoping someone has some documentation on it that explains how to use this properly?

Comment: React doesn't add that stuff be default.  Are you using styled components or something else that might be generating those classes?

Comment: I did not write the react and do know much about it (dev bounced), I am just trying to fix some styles. It might be easier to just add a normal selector to the react: <div className={homeStyles.homeHeader}> but I don't know the proper syntax?

Comment: There is no "proper syntax".  Treat it like you would any div, add classes as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

There's no special meaning or behaviour in CSS. That just matches a class name with sequential hyphen characters in it.